# Adding controls to DataGridView which is bound to a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am developing an `WinForm` app. On my app there is one `DataGridView` control which is bound to one `DataTable` object. Now I want to show the user `ProgressBar` in one specific column of it but I want to do that using `DataTable` object only. I tried this but nothing seems work

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("string", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Progress", typeof(ProgressBar));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dc2);

            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            dr[0] = 1;
            ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
            p.Value = 35;
            dr[1] = p;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Maybe what I am doing is wrong. Is there any other way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
DataTable _table = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);

DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("string", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Progress", typeof(ProgressBar));
_table.Columns.Add(dc);
_table.Columns.Add(dc2);

DataRow dr = _table.NewRow();
dr["string"] = 1;
ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
p.Value = 35;
dr["Progress"] = p;

_table.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Use `ColumnName` instate of using `ColumnIndex` to insert values in DataRow.

Please check [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2/sample-code-datagridview-progress-bar-column?forum=winformsdatacontrols) to create `ProgressBar` in DGV cell.

Comment: Nada. Doesn't help :(.

Comment: Not any error. Just empty grid.
One thing to mention , instead
`DataTable _table = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);`
I have used 
`dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;`
Cause it returns error null object.

Comment: @GaneshS Ok get it, you need to check link in edited answer to add `ProgressBar` in DGV.